# How would get the value of a div's ID then send it to my PHP file using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

What I am trying to do is have "listings" all with unique id's. When a user clicks on a listing (each has anchor tag), I want to query the database with the listing ID, then display the information on the screen. Im not going to worry about echoing the data back to the website, I just want to send the variable at which the database SELECTS for.
**Script**

```
$(function(){
    $('.tasks-column').on('click', 'a', function(){
        var pid = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/php/info-get.php',
            data: {pid : $('#pid')}
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="1">Listing></a>
<a id="2">Listing</a>
```

**HTML div I want Data in**

```
<div class="DataGoesHereAfterClick"><?=$title?></div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

include 'sqlconnection.php';
$conn = OpenCon();
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT title FROM tasks WHERE pid=?'); $pid = 'pid'; $stmt->bind_param('i', $pid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($title);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
echo json_encode($title);
CloseCon($conn);
?>
```

Comment: This is really close to a great question. If you can post some code that you tried to use that didn't work and not just what you are trying to do with some minimal code it would be there. :)

Comment: just did, currently the data is automatically entering into <?=$title?> without me clicking. it is also just selecting the last listing on my page

Comment: Good deal, I can't help more than that, just reviewing new questions for the basics. I'll have to leave it up to someone that knows more about PHP than how to spell it... and I only do that right about 80% of the time.

Comment: `$('#pid')` doesn't get you the HTML or value, it returns an array of matching elements. Are you sure that's what you want? Maybe `$('#pid').val()`

Comment: the data is getting to the destination div, but its not waiting until i click, and when i click on different listings, it doesnt change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script

```
$(function(){
    $(".listing-act").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/php/info-get.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'pid=' + $(this).attr("id"),
            success: function (response) {
                 $('.DataGoesHereAfterClick').html(response);
            }
           }
```

HTML

```
<a id="1" class="listing-act">Listing></a>
<a id="2" class="listing-act">Listing</a>
```

PHP

```
<?php

include 'sqlconnection.php';
$conn = OpenCon();
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT title FROM tasks WHERE pid='.$_POST['pid']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($title);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
echo json_encode($title);
CloseCon($conn);
?>
```

Comment: as of right now the destination div is getting a listing title, but its the last one, and the div is not waiting for the data until the onclick

Comment: You need to get the ID being sent via POST in the PHP script!

Replace:
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT title FROM tasks WHERE pid=?'); $pid = 'pid'; $stmt->bind_param('i', $pid);

To:
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT title FROM tasks WHERE pid='.$_POST['pid']);

Comment: got it working, you are a god myfriend!!!!! may i donate for your assistance please?

Comment: I'm happy to contribute. [Donate here](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=VFCJDPHHVARJE&source=url)